# How to create shortcuts having two target

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am creating a shortcut using the following script:

```
Set oShellLink = objShell.CreateShortcut("shortcut.lnk")
oShellLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe D:\path\to\file.hta"
oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
oShellLink.IconLocation = "logo.ico"
oShellLink.Description = "app"
oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = desktop
oShellLink.Save
```

At `oShellLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe D:\path\to\file.hta"` it's stuck as there is a space in the target path. How to accomplish this? I tried manipulating string like this also.

```
"C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe" & " " & """" & "D:\PLR\software\plrplus.dll" & """"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

> <sup>From [TargetPath property - Remarks Section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/594k4c67(v=vs.84).aspx)</sup>
>   *This property is for the shortcut's target path only. Any arguments to the shortcut must be placed in the Argument's property.*

Arguments to a command belong in the [`Arguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property:

```
Set oShellLink = objShell.CreateShortcut("shortcut.lnk")
oShellLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe"
oShellLink.Arguments = "D:\path\to\file.hta"
...
oShellLink.Save
```

Comment: As I said, I never feel alone using VBscript.

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject That's no reason not to read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), asking here should be a last resort.

Comment: documentation suggested is the same that I used for the example but it did not explained directly about how oShellLink.Arguments is obvious.as I have no idea how object orientation works.

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject And [this doesn't](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s(v=vs.84).aspx)? Any value passed at the end of a path in UNIX, Windows etc is known as an argument *(sometimes a parameter)*. My point is it doesn't take much *(just a little digging)* to workout how arguments should be specified.

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject In fact the [`TargetPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/594k4c67(v=vs.84).aspx) property page say's this in the Remarks section - *"This property is for the shortcut's target path only. **Any arguments to the shortcut must be placed in the Argument's property**."*, pretty clear to me.

Comment: Ok. I agree. I even didn't know what do you mean by 'Any arguments to the shortcut must be placed in the Argument's property.'

Comment: @Lankymart: That's hindsight construction. If everything is understandable from documentation, what is need of stackoverflow?